# from import adds another execution of functions

Tags: python, python-import

Created a python 'library' module which contains functions that I use a lot. Importing this module into a script which does a test using

```
from 'library name' import *
```

However whenever I import the test script using

```
from 'script name' import *
```

All the function calls in the test script execute twice.

I'm pretty sure this is an import issue, but I don't know enough about python to fix it.

Example:
Library.py

```
doSomething()
    print "Library"
```

Test.py

```
from Library import *
doSomething()
```

This will output:
  "Library"
  "Library"

Comment: unreproducible - perhaps we're missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following at the button of your module to eliminate running your module as a script

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    execution code here
```

This will tell Python what code to run **when you are executing** your module as a script. Otherwise, it will just load the module namespace

[Python's **main** docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

> '**main**' is the name of the scope in which top-level code executes. A module’s **name** is set equal to '**main**' when read from standard input, a script, or from an interactive prompt.
>
> A module can discover whether or not it is running in the main scope by checking its own **name**, which allows a common idiom for conditionally executing code in a module when it is run as a script or with python -m but not when it is imported.

Comment: I want it to load the namespace. The problem is that it seems to be loading the namespace twice

Comment: Thinking on it now I want to be able to from import the test so I can run it as part of test group

Comment: So add `if __name__ == '__main__': pass` in your library module, and for the test script add the same statement but insert instructions instead of the `pass` statement

Comment: I don't think that will help, cause all the modules that I don't want run as scripts only contain functions and 'constant' variable declarations

Comment: Since you `from library import *` to your script modules, it is loaded to the script namespace and executed. Try my suggestion

Comment: I'm still getting the doubling up. I don't think I explained it the best. So I have two modules (library and test) and a script which calls a function in the test module. The modules only contain functions, so they won't execute anything when loaded. When I from import Multiple tests (not the same one over and over), which from import the library module then I get doubling and tripling of function calls

Comment: Did you try adding the if name == main statement to the **actual** script you are executing? your actual `__main__` namespace?

Comment: I don't think it is a __name__ issue cause when I do the from imports manually I still get the same issue. It seems like python's include guard isn't working

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue related to python's logging function. logger.getLogger(**name**)